# Freertos hardfault analysis - stack registers

Tags: c++, c, assembly, freertos, cortex-m

I was stumbling over the freertos hardfault handler and its analysis to get out the cause of the fault by loading the stack registers into ram.

Its written in assembly. Is there a way i can translate this to c code and execute?

```
static void HardFault_Handler(void) { __asm volatile ( " tst lr, #4 \n" " ite eq \n" " mrseq r0, msp \n" " mrsne r0, psp \n" " ldr r1, [r0, #24] \n" " ldr r2, handler2_address_const \n" " bx r2 \n" " handler2_address_const: .word prvGetRegistersFromStack \n" ); }
```

From

[enter link description here](https://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html)

Answer (score 1):

That function only retrieves a pointer to the stack, where all the registers' contents before the exception are stored (I.e. for the ARM Cortex M7, you can find more information about exception frames [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0646b/Babefdjc.html)).

Then it calls the function `prvGetRegistersFromStack`, which is already written in `C`, where you can check all the registers from the defined variables (`r0`, `r1` and so on).

One of this registers, `pc`, stores the address of the instruction which caused the hard-fault. You can check the memory map in order to find which function has caused it.

Following that function, in the page you are referring to, there is a section called "Using the register values", which explains how to set a breakpoint from an instruction address.

There is no need to translate anything, FreeRTOS has already done it for you.

Comment: hi, thanks. the problem is that prvGetRegistersFromStack jumps back to the reset handler even if interrupts are disabled (i call   __disable_fault_irq();  __disable_irq(); before the assably code now). this for i never get to the register loader function (prvGetRegistersFromStack)